# pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11 doesn't work with Java7

Tags: pact

pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11 works with Java8, but not Java7. Getting the following error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:3.5.0:verify (default-cli) on project product-xapi-service: Execution default-cli of goal au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:3.5.0:verify failed: Unable to load the mojo 'verify' in the plugin 'au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:3.5.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: au/com/dius/pact/provider/maven/PactProviderMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I don't see the mention of requirement of Java 8 as well. Does it support Java 7 at all?

Comment: Please post this issue on the github page for the project: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i find the documentation specifying the versions here https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm. Thanks.